# How to combine K-means clustering with Naive Bayes

Tags: k-means, naivebayes

Recently,I read some paper about K-means and Naive Bayes learning approach.But I am confused about how to combine these two methods together.

For example, X(x1,x2,x3,...,xn) denotes data record.Label denotes the class which data record Xi belongs to.Assume there are two classes denoted as K1 and K2.
So, we always have Xi (i∈[1,n]) belongs to {K1,K2}

As is known to all, K-means method can cluster data record X.Suppose K=2.Then we have Clx(Clx(i)∈{1,2}, i∈[1，n]) denote the clustering result.

Naive Bayes can calculate the probability. if P(K1|X)>P(K2|X)} then sample X can be classified to class K1. Otherwise X can be classified to class K2.

We can calculate probability using Bayes' theorem.

P(K1|X)=P(X|K1)P(K1)/P(X)=P(x1|K1)P(x2|K1)...P(xn|K1)/P(X)

But How can I combine K-means with Naive Bayes?

So, I think I can use XX denotes (X,Clx).And then use XX to train Naive Bayes Classifier like nb=NaiveBayes.fit(XX,Label,'Distribution', 'normal').

Then I test the classifier I trained before, the result is so depressing.

Am I wrong?

Is this the way to combine these two methods?

Comment: Why do you want to combine K-means with Naive Bayes? Also, which Naive Bayes are you referring to (Multinomial, Bernoulli, Gaussian)?

Comment: I think ‘normal’ in matlab refers to Gaussian. I read a paper which combines K-means with Naive Bayes, and the paper achieved a high detection rate. I want to implement this combination. But I wonder the theory of combination.

Answer (score 1):

After some quick googling I've arrived at [this](http://scialert.net/abstract/?doi=itj.2011.648.655) paper by Muda et al. which describes a K-means-NB combination for the task of intrusion detection.

The model consists of multiple NB classifiers, each trained on a subset of data corresponding to a specific K-means cluster. The authors do not give any theoretical justifications for the proposed combination and I think the reason is simple: there is none [*]. K-means preprocessing is used as an ad-hoc way to train multiple different NB classifiers. The same result could be achieved by using a proper [ensembling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning), e.g. bagging, boosting or stacking.

[*] You could view the combination as a hierarchical probabilistic model. But, the assumptions of such a model would be inconsistent. Conditioned on the cluster, X is assumed to be a sample from a multivariate Gaussian (K-means assumption) and, at the same time, from a *mixture* of multivariate Gaussians (Gaussian NB assumption). Clearly, both of these can't hold at the same time.